# CUDA and OpenCV. Conversion form Mat to GpuMat doesn't work

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I have a little piece of code that try to convert a Mat to GpuMat and reverse.
When I try to upload the Mat in GpuMat with "upload" function, it breaks. If I go next step in the debug the size of GpuMat is written, same as Mat but it doesn't upload the pixel data.
Here is the code:

```
Mat initFrame;
Mat initconv;
Mat threshold;
imageCircle.copyTo(initFrame);
cvtColor(initFrame,initconv,CV_BGR2HSV);

gpu::GpuMat myFrame;
gpu::GpuMat myFrameLab;

myFrame.upload(initconv);

myFrame.download(threshold);
//gpu::cvtColor(myFrame,myFrameLab,CV_BGR2YCrCb);
imshow("INPUT",threshold);
```

**UPDATE**

I read that I will need Opencv built with GPU support. Here I don't know what to do. I saw somewhere that in OpenCV directories it exist `/gpu/built/..`. I have 2.4.9 and 3.1 versions but I don't find in Opencv directory the `/gpu/build/...`

Comment: Please define what you mean by "it breaks". How does "it break"?

Comment: cv::Exception at memory location 0x001eaac4. I have memory acces violation. I verified if I have the opencv built with GPU support and unfortunately is right. I need to get opencv built with GPU support or what? Here I don't understand.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with that information instead of posting it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It begins to be an old post, but still I'd like to help:

First, to verify if Cuda is installed and is supported , you have to call the function

```
cuda::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount();
```

If Cuda is installed and supported,, then it has to return something different than 0.
If you're using Visual Studio 2015 like me , usually you should be knowing that Cuda only supports Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015 Update 1
In my research about using Cuda, I followed this tutorial :
http://robbinmarcus.blogspot.fr/2016/02/cuda-in-visual-studio-2015.html
Let me know if you need help